# How to add multiple accounts using google drive sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, google-drive-api

I need to create an app which includes multiple google accounts. I need to be able to query any of the accounts which the user had logged in. How do I do it using objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no special feature you need to support this feature. You just save credential for each accounts and query each of them as you need. Here is [quickstart for object-c](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios). To be specific, in this quickstart, you can make multiple `GTLServiceDrive` objects else than `driveService` and authorize each of them to query different accounts a t a same time.